# How to fix 'Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX is not defined' when importing a class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, import, referenceerror

I am having trouble importing/exporting classes. It seems so hit and miss.  Sometimes it works other times it won't.

I receive the following console error:
    Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined at main.js:

I have uploaded this test online http://tibbotts.epizy.com/testClassImport/index.html

I have tried changing "./test.js" to "/test.js", "./test" etc..

I have tried searching the web for solutions, but all solutions are geared towards the script type="module" ... fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Test Class Importing</title>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    hello this is a test
</body>

</html>
```

```
import Test from "./test.js";

test = new Test();

test.speak();
```

```
export default class Test{

    constructor(test){
        this._test = `Test is Successful`;
    }

    speak(){
        console.log(this._test);
    }

}
```

I am expecting this to console log `Test is Successful` and import the script but am instead getting the following error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined at main.js:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to initialize `test` with a keyword like `var` or `let` :

```
let test = new Test();
```

Also don't forget that your constructor function expects an argument:

```
let test = new Test("something");
```

Comment: Thank you! I stepped away from the keyboard for a few moments and when I returned I saw the reason staring at me and I was frantically trying to figure a way of removing my question before anyone answered! I guess I should have tried stepping away from the keyboard first! Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Comment: No worries @minlopalis, always glad to help.